# git reset -- hard with to previous commit set local and remote repository

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I want to do a git reset to a previous commit. I want my local repo to reflect the changes when I go back to the old commit and I want my remote repo to do the same. How do I do this?

Comment: So, you want to remove the commit from local as well as from remote is it?

Comment: yep yep yep yep yep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- git reset HEAD~1
- git stash save 'Save the commit changes just in case'
- git push origin -f `your_branch_name`

Check this article out as well https://ncona.com/2011/07/how-to-delete-a-commit-in-git-local-and-remote/

**DISCLAIMER:** Force push is not at all safe but that is the only way I know to remove commits from remote.

Comment: perfect the git push origin -f is what I needed very sexy man. thanks sexy man

Comment: if you upvote my question as well I would appreciate it. Need points